How to get the height of the Android's bellow navbar swipe feature?

Check the picture...I am actually trying to create a container whose height should be the whole height of the viewport without considering the top safe area and also subtracting the bottom tab bar/nav bar height.
in other words: the device screen height minus the navbar minus the thing bellow to the navbar (the black one very in the bottom of the screen , bellow to the grey nav bar that belongs to the OS where you can swipe up and invoke a feature accordin with the device version/model)
I made several attempts with no success...This is my last one...
void _calculateBottomPadding() {
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  final viewInsets = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
  final viewPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom;
  setState(() {
    _bottomPadding = viewInsets > 0 ? viewInsets : viewPadding;
  });
});
}



 Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom -
        _bottomPadding -
        kBottomNavigationBarHeight,

Any help?

So you want your app to draw behind the NavBar instead of having the black background?

no, @Lee3...I just want to know the height
